# How to find min String from a delimited string in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a delimited string stored in a variable.

```
date_str = 2017-04-03,2017-04-04,2017-04-05
```

How do I take the min value out of this delimited string using linux

Expected output is --> 2017-04-03

Could some one help me to do that?

Comment: `awk -F, '{ print $1 }' <<< "$date_str"`

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -v d=$date_str '     # set variable to awk var d
BEGIN {
    n=split(d,a,",")       # split to a on ,
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)      # iterate thru a
        if(m==""||a[i]<m)  # compare to current min m
            m=a[i]      
    print m                # after everything print min m
}'
2017-04-03
```

Regarding comments:

```
$ echo $date_str | awk -v RS=, 'NR==1||$0<m{m=$0}END{print m}'
2017-04-03
```

Comment: You can use `-F,` to split by `,`

Comment: @hek2mgl I could if I piped the data in from the variable in which case I'd `set -v RS=,` and loose the `for` also.

Comment: Just realized that you run this in the `BEGIN` block. Must have been blind. It's ok then!

Answer (score 3):

Short **gawk** approach:

```
awk -v d=$date_str 'BEGIN{split(d,a,","); asort(a); print a[1]}'
```

The output:

```
2017-04-03
```

---

`split(d,a,",")` - splits "date" string into pieces separated by `,`

`asort(a)` - sorts an array values

`a[1]` - represents the first item of sorted array

Comment: Golfing (~10 chars shorter) : `awk '{a[$1]}END{asorti(a);print a[1]}' RS="," <<<"$d"`

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

`echo "date_str = 2017-04-03,2017-04-04,2017-04-05" | grep -Po "[0-9][^,]+" | sort -n  | head -n 1`

result is:

`2017-04-03`

Answer (score 0):

If you need sorting by date

```
#!/bin/sh

STR='2017-04-03,2017-04-04,2017-04-05,2017-02-23,2017-04-25,2017-03-12,2016-08-25';

TS_ARR=();
IFS=',' read -r -a dates <<< $STR
for next_date in ${dates[@]}; do
  date_ts=`date --date="${next_date}" +%s`
  TS_ARR+=($date_ts)
done
IFS=$'\n' SORT_TS=($(sort <<< "${TS_ARR[*]}"))
echo "sorted: `date -d @${SORT_TS[0]} +%Y-%m-%d`"
```

Should show you `sorted: 2016-08-25`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that converts the strings to seconds from epoch, sorts them, grabs the first one and converts it back to a string:

```
date_str="2017-04-03,2017-04-04,2017-04-05"
while IFS=, read -r -a arr || [[ -n $arr ]]; do
    for str in ${arr[*]}; do
        echo $(date -d "$str" +%s)
    done
done <<<"$date_str" |
sort -n |
head -n 1 |
{ read -r earliest; date -d @"${earliest}" +%F ; }
```